# Combining SimpleOneWayItinerary items, from BFM in OTA_AirBookRQ

Tags: sabre

I am having issues, combining some fares, from `Bargain Finder Max`'s `SimpleOneWayItineraries` (SOAP), when sending to `OTA_AirBookRQ`. The issue happens simply because some of these one-way fares are not combinable. When sending those itineraries together, the response is the famous `NO COMBINABLE FARES FOR CLASS USED`.

I suspect, in order to avoid sending these faulty requests, BFM would supply me with a piece of information, that signifies which fares can be priced together.

Despite searching the docs, over and over, I have not found an indicator on each `PricedItinerary` that signals such information.

Please let me know if the indicator exist, or better yet, how I can avoid displaying these faulty combination of fares, from Bargain Finder Max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only alternative is to enable Multi-Ticket, which will produce a different ticket for each fare component.

In cases where carriers do not have an agreement, this allows you to combine searches.

It will also retrieve compatible fares if that criteria is met.

I hope this information was useful.